# Is it best practice to create a back door for testing a web service?

Tags: testing, web-services

We have a public RESTful web service which exposes functionality to third parties. We are writing automated tests against it. In order to set up all scenarios on it we need to change the data behind it.

We also have a private RESTful web service which exposes functionality to other systems owned by us. However, this web service does not expose endpoints required to set up all the scenarios for the public web service.

In this circumstance is it best to create extra endpoints, not needed in normal operational behaviour, on the private web service in order to support the testing of the public one? Or should we set up our data using other means such as sending SQL commands?

Comment: Wouldn't having separate endpoints sort of defeat the purpose of testing?

Comment: If it's not possible for your API clients to set up the scenario in a certain way, why are you trying to test that scenario?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson there's also a web application in the mix - users will go into the web application and change the data. So we want to be able to mimic various actions of those users and test their effect on the behaviour of the web service.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Do you mean that the new endpoints provide more potential to be incorrect?

Comment: @PollyShaw but your web app is also an API client, no? Even if it has access to the whole of your API and third-party clients can only use a subset, it sounds like you're saying certain situations will still be impossible to set up.

Comment: No the web app doesn't depend on the API. It uses a middle tier which is also used by both APIs but isn't generally available.

Comment: In general I would avoid exposing something like this as I'm not sure I've encountered a scenario that I couldn't test these sort of functionalities in isolation through unit (or unit-ish) testing in one way or another. Perhaps I'm mistaken

Comment: @PollyShaw - in that case, your service boundary is the middle tier. You should write your acceptance tests against that. Then you have the option of mocking-out the middle tier when you're testing your API and web app.

Comment: The endpoints are not the real endpoints.  By definition, you're not testing the system that your users are actually going to use.  You can get a *partial* test this way, but not a comprehensive one.  And I get nervous every time someone mentions the use of a "back door."  Back doors should only exist in the movie "War Games".

Comment: So no, it's not a "best practice."

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, yes I agree. The problem is that we are trying to use SOAP UI which doesn't have the capability to set up self-hosted services. But we haven't done enough 'unit-ish' testing. I'd be happier with having less comprehensive integration tests if we had.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a mocking framework like Mockito to create a mock of the private service for the purpose of testing the other one?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner The public service doesn't call the private service - they both call a middle tier.

Comment: @PollyShaw: Sorry, it sounded like you were contemplating creating new endpoints in the private service to facilitate testing of the public service. I was thinking it might be easier to test the public service against a *mock* of the private service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a need to create back doors for testing.

If you're making use of repo pattern or something similar then test you data access logic separately, and mock your repo in services when testing (I assume you're unit-testing them?). This way you can validate if service calls the correct repo methods with correct inputs.

This was working out pretty well for us.